# Determining a Regex for split()

Tags: groovy

I have a string, which represents a version:

```
 abc-5.18.0.0_10
```

I'm trying to determine the regex to extract this subString:

```
 abc-5.18.0
```

This in format terms is:
We want any characters up until the "-". 
We also want between the "-" and the first '." which is the major version 1 to nn. 
We also want between the first "." and the second "." which is the minor version 0 to nn.
We also want the subminor version between the second and third ".", 0-nn.

xxx-nn.nn.nn

I'm trying this:

```
 .split("//|\\.")
```

And I'm getting this:

```
 abc-5.18
```

What am I doing wrong? Should it be "///|\."?

Comment: It's not completely clear what the general format of these strings is and what you're trying to extract. Describe in words what the pattern is.

Comment: Re-edited the original post

Comment: It's easier to search for the positive space rather than splitting on the negative space. I think a simpler description of what you want is from the start to before the third period?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I want everything to the left of the third period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use restrictive regular expression like:

```
^([^-]+-\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(\..*)?$
```

You can apply it and extract the value in the following way in Groovy:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

final String str = 'abc-5.18.0.0_10'

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(/^([^-]+-\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(\..*)?$/)

final String result = (str =~ pattern).replaceFirst('$1')

println result
```

Output:

```
abc-5.18.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the regex you want is stuff, period, stuff, period, stuff up to the third period.

This uses a group () to capture what you want. It looks confusing because `.` represents any character and `\.` represents a period.

```
s = 'abc-5.18.0.0_10'
re.match(r"(.*\..*\..*)\.", s).group(1)

Out: 'abc-5.18.0'
```